# Do I need an outlet box to install an outdoor light fixture?

Tags: lighting, installation

We're getting a sliding door and deck installed this week and the town inspector said I need to have an outside light by the door.  I'm ready to tackle this part myself.   Most of the howto stuff I find online says "It's easy, just remove the existing light fixture..." and I have no existing light fixture.

Do I need to cut a large hole in the aluminum siding and mount an outlet box to attach the fixture to?  If so, how do I secure it?

Or is there a very low-profile outlet box I can put flush to the siding that won't stick out too much and won't require a huge hole?

Some of the fixtures in my house (not sure about the outdoor ones) have been installed without boxes altogether.  I'm guessing this is not code, and I'm further guessing this is a corner that one shouldn't cut for outdoor lighting.  Especially since the wall cavity has blown-in cellulose insulation--I feel like I should avoid having splices in contact with that.

**Edit** Thanks for the help.  In the end I went with the large hole and retrofit light box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Electrical code requires that all junctions be accessible in a box, so you definitely need one here.  You have two choices (that I know of at least):

- cut a large hole in your siding and mount a [retrofit light box](http://www.homedepot.com/Electrical-Electrical-Boxes-Conduit-Fittings-Boxes-Brackets/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xh8Zbohn/R-100404072/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) into the wall cavity.

[image: remodel box]

- drill a small hole in your siding and mount one a [weatherproof box](http://www.homedepot.com/Electrical-Electrical-Boxes-Conduit-Fittings-Boxes-Brackets/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xh8Zbohn/R-202284526/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) on the outside:

[image: exterior box]

The exterior boxes come in a range of depths and colors so you should be able to find one you like.

Comment: Is the retrofit light box shown OK for outside use?

Comment: @vebjorn: one of my [wiring books](http://www.amazon.com/Black-Decker-Complete-Guide-Wiring/dp/1589234138/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1289659994&sr=8-1) shows one being used in an exterior location with a rubber gasket (supposed to come with the light) and a grounding clip on the box if the light fixture doesn't have a grounding stud.  Are you concerned about water getting into the wall cavity?

Comment: Yes, I am concerned about water getting into the wall cavity.

Comment: FWIW, I caulked around the fixture where it contacts the wall.

Comment: "cut a large hole in your siding" seems insensitive to the difficulty of restoring the waterproofing.  Mold, rot and termites can follow.  Downvoting until that issue is addressed.  The retrofit box in particular cannot be water sealed.

Comment: Dead links on the box descriptions!